CSS Has with Not issue
How can I get the .statistics-list that contains a ul with no li's to be hidden?


.statistics-section {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.statistics-section:has(ul:has(:not(li))) {
  display: none;
}
<div class="statistics-section">
  <h2>Hello 1 - This should be visible</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="statistics-section">
  <h2>Hello 2 - This should be hidden</h2>
  <ul></ul>
</div>




Please include the code in the question as text rather than an external link (you can use the snippet tool to create a functional example)

Ok.  I will do next time.  For now i'll just add the code

Test if there is any li. No need to include the ul in the selection


.statistics-section {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.statistics-section:not(:has(li)) {
  display: none;
}
<div class="statistics-section">
  <h2>Hello 1 - This should be visible</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="statistics-section">
    <h2>Hello 2 - This should be hidden</h2>
  <ul></ul>
</div>



Or test an empty ul


.statistics-section {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.statistics-section:has(ul:empty) {
  display: none;
}
<div class="statistics-section">
  <h2>Hello 1 - This should be visible</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="statistics-section">
    <h2>Hello 2 - This should be hidden</h2>
  <ul></ul>
</div>




Obligatory word of caution about :empty, it won't match if there is any text node in the element, so depending on how the elements have been removed it may very well fail in some hard to debug ways.

You can also hide the ones that are misiing an ul>li


.statistics-section {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.statistics-section:not(:has(ul > li)) {
  display: none;
}
<div class="statistics-section">
  <h2>Hello 1 - This should be visible</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="statistics-section">
  <h2>Hello 2 - This should be hidden</h2>
  <ul></ul>
</div>



